# ZFS on Centos - "No such pool or dataset" and "devices is currently unavailable"

Tags: centos, zfs, centos7, zfsonlinux

I'm trying to create zpools on CentOS 7 (3.10.0-327.10.1), and the zpool command seems to hate "wwn-0x" IDs.

"zpool status" is clear - there are no zpools currently configured on the machine.  I have drives:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    9 Mar 11 14:30 wwn-0x5000cca2440ba0a0 -> ../../sds
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    9 Mar 11 14:30 wwn-0x5000cca2440ba1dc -> ../../sdu
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    9 Mar 11 14:30 wwn-0x5000cca2440992cc -> ../../sdl
```

If I type:

```
zpool create -f asdf /dev/sds /dev/sdu /dev/sdl
```

It works great.

If I use the WWN IDs, however, I get errors, depending on what I send it:

```
zpool create -f asdf wwn-0x5000cca2440ba0a0 wwn-0x5000cca2440ba1dc wwn-0x5000cca2440992cc
```

Yields:

```
cannot create 'asdf': no such pool or dataset
```

And typing (adding the keyword "mirror"):

```
zpool create -f asdf mirror wwn-0x5000cca2440ba0a0 wwn-0x5000cca2440ba1dc wwn-0x5000cca2440992cc
```

Yields:

```
cannot create 'asdf': one or more devices is currently unavailable
```

Specifying the full path, "/dev/disk/by-id/" + WWN, yields the same results.

This works great on Ubuntu.  What's going on here?  Does anyone know?  Is it a bug in ZOL?

Answer (score 1):

*"one or more devices is currently unavailable"*

That's a misleading message.

What does your `fdisk -l` show?

You can use full paths if you want, but I suspect your syntax is wrong...
Also, the easiest approach is to run the command from within the `/dev/disk/by-id/` directory.

Make sense?

This is what I would build a ZFS mirrors/striped set with:

> zpool create vol0 -o ashift=13 -o autoexpand=on -o autoreplace=on -f
>   mirror wwn-0x5001e8200262d41c wwn-0x5001e8200262cf48 mirror
>   wwn-0x5001e8200262cbdc wwn-0x5001e82002758f94 mirror
>   wwn-0x5001e8200262cf18 wwn-0x5001e82002759358 mirror
>   wwn-0x5001e8200262d0c4 wwn-0x5001e820027591bc

So your command line should look like:

> zpool create asdf -f mirror wwn-0x5000cca2440ba0a0
>   wwn-0x5000cca2440ba1dc mirror wwn-0x5000cca2440992cc